# custom scopes based on application

Tags: django, django-oauth-toolkit

I am trying to define different scopes for each oauth application in Django-oauth-toolkit.
I realized I can define different scopes on the settings file. But it seems that they apply to every new oauth-application I create.

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'SCOPES': {
        'read': 'Read scope',
        'write': 'Write scope',
        'custom': 'Custom scope.'
    },
```

Is there a way to define scopes for a particular oauth-application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the scopes need to differ they must be included in the request to get an access token as specified [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-3.3).

So basically the request to get an access token should look like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/noexist/callback&scope=write+custom
```